# MVC view path from VisualStudio fails

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

When I right click on my view file (RetrieveReport.cshtml) and select "Properties" I find the "Browse to URL" property has this value: "~/Reports/HtmlReport/RetrieveReport"

Then when I try to do this in my controller:

```
return View("~/Reports/HtmlReport/RetrieveReport");
```

I get:

> The view '~/Reports/HtmlReport/RetrieveReport' or its master was not
>   found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following
>   locations were searched: ~/Reports/HtmlReport/RetrieveReport

That seems messed up since that is verbatim what VisualStudio told me to put in there!

I tried returning views with all of these paths:

> ~/Reports/HtmlReport/RetrieveReport.cshtml HtmlReport/RetrieveReport
>   /Reports/HtmlReport/RetrieveReport Reports/HtmlReport/RetrieveReport
>   RetrieveReport

None of them succeed. I thought at one point RetrieveReport was working, but now it seems to not be working.

In case it helps at all, the location on the file system is:

> C:\Users\micah_000\Desktop\source_11_19_2014\GideonWeb\Areas\Reports\Views\HtmlReport\RetrieveReport.cshtml

In my solution explorer the file is at:

> Areas -> Reports -> Views -> HtmlReport -> RetrieveReport.cshtml

Comment: This is not visual studio related as its simply the IDE. The framework could not find your view because the "~" operator implies the root of your solution and you missed out the Areas folder. The MVC framework has default search locations that are quite greedy when located in the Areas and Views folder, but outside of this you would need to configure the ViewEngine to look there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing this work elsewhere in our codebase this worked for me:

> ~/Areas/Reports/Views/HtmlReport/RetrieveReport.cshtml

Still don't know why VisualStudio was pointing to a dead end ...